# GRE eigenvalue question. Do we actually have to find the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, gre-exam

The GRE is this weekend and while working through a practice test I came across this question, and I couldn't see any clever way to work out the answer.

Of 2, 3, and 5, which are the eigenvalues of the following:
\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 5 & 3  \\
    1 & 7 & 3\\
    1 &2 &8 \\
\end{bmatrix}

$A)$ None B)2, 3 C)2, 5 D)3, 5  E)2, 3, 5

I've found that often in these tests we can eliminate some of the answers based on the determinant or the trace, but for this one I'm stuck (the answer is C). Of course, I know that it could be the case that we actually have to work it out, I'm just hoping it isn't.

Comment: Unless there's some trick in some old Russian Math book (which always seems to be the case!) short of working it out, I can't see a way to compute the eigenvalues that doesn't involve solving for the roots of a characteristic polynomial.

Comment: You can at least rule out (E) using the trace.

Comment: @carmichael561 Thanks! I should have said that I got that far.

Comment: @IkjyotSinghKohli That's what I was hoping for. But thanks anyway. Should I delete the question or leave it up for viewing?

Comment: Its easy to prove 2 is not an eigenvalue, since the first two rows of the matrix A-2I are the same. Same goes for the last two rows of A-5I. It's not easy to determine if 3 is or not, but knowing 2 and 5 aren't eigenvalues  only leaves answer (A) as a possibility.

Comment: @MikeEarnest 2 is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Oops, that was dumb of me! I should have said that it's easy to prove 2 and 5 are eigenvalues, because those matrices have repeated rows and are therefore singular. Then you rule out the 2,3,5 option using the trace.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I actually like this method. It's pretty obvious now, but I've never had many computational linear algebra problems. If you want to post as an answer I will upvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you apply the determinantal definition of the characteristic polynomial, you can readily verify that 2 and 5 are eigenvalues (what do the resulting matrices look like?).  Since you've indicated that you can eliminate (E) via the trace, this leaves (C) as the only option.

For example, the matrix for testing 2 is

$$
        \left(\begin{matrix}
        3 - 2 & 5 & 3 \\
        1 & 7 - 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 8 - 2 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
=
        \left(\begin{matrix}
        1 & 5 & 3 \\
        1 & 5 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 6 \\
        \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. I guess it's actually not that bad because we don't have to expand the characteristic polynomial, just test the roots. I should have realized that sooner but I was so caught up in not doing any work that I didn't realize it's not that much work.